# Connecting a convolverNode to a userGetMedia input--(Web Audio API)+audio tag

Tags: javascript, html, laravel-5.5, web-audio-api

I am trying to understand the Web Audio API and need some help.

I want to connect a convolverNode to a live recorded clip

The following code interacts with the html play and stop button and input tag with type="range" it adds reverb and works perfectly.

```
 var context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();

 var source;
 var convolverGain = context.createGain();
 var convolver = context.createConvolver();
 var masterGain = context.createGain();
 var masterCompression = context.createDynamicsCompressor();

var impulseUrl = 'audio/impulse2.wav';
var sourceUrl = 'audio/test.wav';

var play2 = document.querySelector('.play2');
var stop2 = document.querySelector('.stop2');
stop2.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

var convolverGainControl = document.querySelector('.convolver-gain-
control');
var convolverGainValue = document.querySelector('.convolver-gain-value');
 convolverGainControl.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');

function getSource() {

  source = context.createBufferSource();
  request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', sourceUrl, true);
  request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

  request.onload = function() {
  var audioData = request.response;

    context.decodeAudioData(audioData, function(buffer) {
    myBuffer = buffer;
    source.buffer = myBuffer;
    source.loop = true;
    source.connect(convolverGain);
    source.connect(masterGain);
    masterGain.connect(masterCompression);
    masterCompression.connect(context.destination);

      },

      function(e){"Error with decoding audio data" + e.err});

  }

 request.send();

  getImpulse();

  document.querySelector('.convolver-gain-control').value = '0';
  document.querySelector('.convolver-gain-
  control').addEventListener('change', function() {
  convolverGainControl.value = this.value;
  });

}

function getImpulse() {
  convolver = context.createConvolver();
  ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajaxRequest.open('GET', impulseUrl, true);
  ajaxRequest.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

   ajaxRequest.onload = function() {
   var impulseData = ajaxRequest.response;

   context.decodeAudioData(impulseData, function(buffer) {
        myImpulseBuffer = buffer;
        convolver.buffer = myImpulseBuffer;
        convolver.loop = true;
    convolver.normalize = true;
    convolverGain.gain.value = 0;
    convolverGain.connect(convolver);
    convolver.connect(masterGain);
      },

      function(e){"Error with decoding audio data" + e.err});

  }

  ajaxRequest.send();
}

 play2.onclick = function() {
 convolver.disconnect();
 getSource();
 source.start(0);
 play2.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
 convolverGainControl.removeAttribute('disabled');
 stop2.removeAttribute('disabled');
 convolverGainValue.innerHTML = 0;
 }

stop2.onclick = function() {
source.stop(0);
play2.removeAttribute('disabled');
convolverGainControl.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
stop2.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
 }

convolverGainControl.oninput = function() {
convolverGain.gain.value = convolverGainControl.value;
convolverGainValue.innerHTML = convolverGainControl.value;
 }
```

The following code I found, has a record and stop button and a visualizer 
it records a clip and adds it to the bottom of the page when finished recording.

```
// set up basic variables for app

var record = document.querySelector('.record');
var stop = document.querySelector('.stops');
var soundClips = document.querySelector('.sound-clips');
var canvas = document.querySelector('.visualizer');
var mainSection = document.querySelector('.main-controls');

// disable stop button while not recording

stop.disabled = true;

// visualiser setup - create web audio api context and canvas

var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || webkitAudioContext)();
var canvasCtx = canvas.getContext("2d");

//main block for doing the audio recording

if (navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
  console.log('getUserMedia supported.');

  var constraints = { audio: true };
  var chunks = [];

  var onSuccess = function(stream) {
    var mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

    visualize(stream);

    record.onclick = function() {
      mediaRecorder.start();
      console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
      console.log("recorder started");
      record.style.background = "red";




      stop.disabled = false;
      record.disabled = true;
    }

    stop.onclick = function() {
      mediaRecorder.stop();
      console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
      console.log("recorder stopped");
      record.style.background = "";
      record.style.color = "";
      // mediaRecorder.requestData();

      stop.disabled = true;
      record.disabled = false;
    }

    mediaRecorder.onstop = function(e) {
      console.log("data available after MediaRecorder.stop() called.");

      var clipName = prompt('Enter a name for your sound clip?','Unnamed clip');
      console.log(clipName);
      var clipContainer = document.createElement('article');
      var clipLabel = document.createElement('p');
      var audio = document.createElement('audio');
      var deleteButton = document.createElement('button');

      clipContainer.classList.add('clip');
        audio.setAttribute('controls', '');
      deleteButton.textContent = 'Delete';
      deleteButton.className = 'delete';

      if(clipName === null) {
        clipLabel.textContent = 'My unnamed clip';
      } else {
        clipLabel.textContent = clipName;
      }

      clipContainer.appendChild(audio);
      clipContainer.appendChild(clipLabel);
      clipContainer.appendChild(deleteButton);
      soundClips.appendChild(clipContainer);

      audio.controls = true;
      var blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });
      chunks = [];
      var audioURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      audio.src = audioURL;
      console.log("recorder stopped");

      deleteButton.onclick = function(e) {
        evtTgt = e.target;
        evtTgt.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(evtTgt.parentNode);
      }

      clipLabel.onclick = function() {
        var existingName = clipLabel.textContent;
        var newClipName = prompt('Enter a name for your sound clip?');
        if(newClipName === null) {
          clipLabel.textContent = existingName;
        } else {
          clipLabel.textContent = newClipName;
        }
      }
    }

    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(e) {
      chunks.push(e.data);
    }
  }

  var onError = function(err) {
    console.log('The following error occured: ' + err);
  }

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(onSuccess, onError);

} else {
   console.log('getUserMedia not supported on your browser!');
}

function visualize(stream) {
  var source = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

  var analyser = audioCtx.createAnalyser();
  analyser.fftSize = 2048;
  var bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
  var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);

  source.connect(analyser);
  //analyser.connect(audioCtx.destination);

  draw()

  function draw() {
    WIDTH = canvas.width
    HEIGHT = canvas.height;

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);

    analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray);

    canvasCtx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)';
    canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    canvasCtx.lineWidth = 2.5;
    canvasCtx.strokeStyle = 'rgb(200, 200, 200)';

    canvasCtx.beginPath();

    var sliceWidth = WIDTH * 1.0 / bufferLength;
    var x = 0;


    for(var i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {

      var v = dataArray[i] / 128.0;
      var y = v * HEIGHT/2;

      if(i === 0) {
        canvasCtx.moveTo(x, y);
      } else {
        canvasCtx.lineTo(x, y);
      }

      x += sliceWidth;
    }

    canvasCtx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height/2);
    canvasCtx.stroke();

  }
}

window.onresize = function() {
  canvas.width = mainSection.offsetWidth;
}

window.onresize();
```

Thus my question.
How do I add the convolverNode to the recorder and how do I create a toggle(mute) button that lets me hear the sounds that come through the microphone.

Thanks in advance.